# In ASP.NET does Response.Redirect hinder the Page_Load event of the target URL?

Tags: redirect, event-handling, pageload

In my ASP.NET Web Forms application I have two pages **MyPage.aspx** and **Login.aspx**.

When the user is in **MyPage** and it is required to login clicks on

```
<a href="~/Login.aspx?ref=~/MyPage.aspx">login</a>
```

The user is brought to **Login.aspx**, enters username and password and clicks on the **login button**. The `login_onClick` event handler performs some operation and then

```
 myUrl = Request.QueryString["ref"];
 Response.Redirect(myUrl); //myUrl = "~/MyPage.aspx"
```

When the page is redirected the `Page_Load` event is not fired (or at least its event handler is not executed). Is it a typical (really odd) behavior of the `Response.Redirect`? If it is the case how can I hinder this behavior, in order to fire `Page_Load`?

PS: I tried to put `Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)` before the redirection with no success

Comment: Are you still looking for more answers to this question? Or have you solved it in another way you can share with the community?

Comment: The problem was very stupid. The person that initally developed the application used absolute urls. That means when it was redirecting, instead of going to the development version it was going to the absolute URL, which referred to the live website. That's why it was never entering page_load during debugging

Comment: Yikes, in that case I may need to revise my answer to include flogging. Are you able to close this question?

Comment: I started the closing process. If you vote there are still 3 to go. thanks

Comment: How/where do I do that? Think it takes more rep than I have.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the browser from using a cached copy of the redirect target, in your case MyPage.aspx, you would need to turn of the cacheability and set the expiration of MyPage.aspx, not placing that before your redirect.
The redirect actually sends a response back to the client browser, telling it to request the other page.  By removing cache right before the redirect call, it is actually telling the browser not to cache the current page, which is still Login.aspx at that time.